# Can battle medicine feat work together with the ward medic feat?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, healing

I have made a character that has the Medic dedication and has both the battle medicine and the ward medic feats. See below for description.

Can my character heal multiple allies during combat combining the 2 feats described below?

> BATTLE MEDICINE
> MEDICINE SKILL FEAT 1
>
> GENERAL
> HEALING
> MANIPULATE
> SKILL
>
> **Prerequisites** trained in Medicine
>
> **Requirements** You are holding or wearing healer’s tools
>
> You can patch up wounds, even in combat. Attempt a Medicine check with the same DC as for Treat Wounds, and restore a corresponding amount of Hit Points; this does not remove the wounded condition. As with Treat Wounds, you can attempt checks against higher DCs if you have the minimum proficiency rank. The target is then temporarily immune to your Battle Medicine for 1 day.

> WARD MEDIC
> MEDICINE SKILL FEAT 2
>
> GENERAL
> SKILL
>
> **Prerequisites** expert in Medicine
>
> You’ve studied in large medical wards, treating several patients at once and tending to all their needs. When you use Treat Disease or Treat Wounds, you can treat up to two targets. If you’re a master in Medicine, you can treat up to four targets, and if you’re legendary, you can treat up to eight targets.

Answer (score 16):

### No, as you are not using Treat Wounds with Battle Medicine

Ward Medic allows you to treat multiple targets when you use Treat Disease or Treat Wounds. Battle Medic allows you to

> Attempt a Medicine check **with the same DC as for** Treat Wounds, and restore a corresponding amount of Hit Point

that is, you are not using Treat Wounds. You are using a Medicine check, that has the same DC as Treat Wounds would have, but it is not Treat Wounds. Because you are not using Treat Wounds, you cannot apply the Ward Medic feat to what you do, as that only works when you do use Treat Wounds (or Treat Disease).

Comment: Has that been errated? I remember it being explicitly a Treat Wounds.

Comment: @AnneAunyme If tAoN includes errata, the [quoted Battle Medicine text is up-to-date](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=760).

Comment: So you can use Battle Medicine and Treat Wounds as soon as you are out of combat?

Comment: @FrancescoRogo You could use Ward Medicine outside of combat. I do not think you could apply Battle Medicine to it, though. Battle Medicine allows you to do its thing, "even in combat", but the requirements would be the same if you are in combat or not in combat. It still is not a use of Treat Wounds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @NobodytheHobgoblin

Comment: @FrancescoRogo you 'can' use Battle Medicine outside of combat but it would probably be a bad idea as you can only use it once per person per day, whereas Treat wounds can be used once per person per hour (which can be shortened with another feat). The only advantage I see in using Battle Medicine outside of actual combat would be if you didn't have 10 minutes to perform a Treat Wounds activity

Comment: What i meant was that you can use Battle Medicine in combat and as soon as combat ends you can Treat Wounds on the same target because it is now immune to Battle Medicine only, am i right?

Comment: @FrancescoRogo Yes, that works. Battle Medicine only blocks additional uses of Battle Medicine that day. You can use Treat Wounds all you want, all day.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin I am also convinced it is up-to-date. I was just wondering if it used to be different or if it always was like that.